# Database table not updating

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am using mysqli and php and what I am trying to do is that I want the user to be able create a new password if they wish to do this.

For a user to change their password, the will enter in their username in the "Username" textbox and then type in their new password in the "New Password" textbox.

When the user submits the form, it should look in the database, find the username which matches in the database and update that row so the previous password changes to a new password and it also salts the password for better encryption.

But the problem is that it is not doing this at all. The database is not updating the password at all, never mind salting them and I can't figure out what I need to do.

Below is my attempt (I have connected to db but just not included that code below):

```
     <?php
          // PHP code
          session_start(); 

          $salt = ""; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) { 
           $salt .= substr(
             "./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 
             mt_rand(0, 63), 
             1); 
        }


          $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
          $newpassword = (isset($_POST['newpassword'])) ? $_POST['newpassword'] : '';

          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
     $query = "UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherSalt = $salt, TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT($newpassword,$salt)) WHERE TeacherUserName = ?";
            // prepare query
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
            // You only need to call bind_param once
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
            // execute query
            $stmt->execute(); 
            // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
            $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword);

            while($stmt->fetch()) {
              if ($username == $dbTeacherUsername) {
                $loggedIn = true;
              }
            }

            /* close statement */
            $stmt->close();

            /* close connection */
            $mysqli->close();


          }

....

          <p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="username" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
          <p>New Password</p><p><input type="password" name="newpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password-->
```

Below is what the database table currently looks like:

```
TeacherUsername    TeacherPassword     TeacherSalt
j.lu               fgrfre4r4ffsdfv
```

So if j.lu wanted to change password, then she will enter in her username and then enter in a new password, then this should all be updated into the table above. But it isn't updating anything.

Thank you

Comment: So what was the problem?  Failing to quote your strings/dates?  Something else? Tell us how you resolved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the username into variable named `$username` but you are binding a variable called `$teacherusername` in bind_param(), which is why the query does not fetch any results.

The bind_param code should be:

```
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
```

Comment: Ok I changed this, (can't believe I made that silly mistake) but it is still not updating the password or include anything under "TeacherSalt" column

Comment: Also I find that you are trying to fetch values into `dbTeacherUsername`  and `dbTeacherPassword` using `$stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword);` but you do not have the query run for fetching those..

Comment: I thought bind_result was needed for UPDATE statement but it is only for SELECT statement. Ok I have done some error reporting and I am getting a fatal error and warning stating this: `Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: (42S22/1054): Unknown column 'i6xX2u35GvDo1vegznNkS34uO903y.XaHlp1hFXd' in 'field list' in ... on line 36`
....
`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in on line 38`

Comment: TeacherPassowrd is that the field name - if it is then it is misspelt :) and in your query you are spelling it correctly as TeacherPassword

Comment: I only spelt TeacherPassword wrong in SO, it is actually spelt correctly in database

Comment: I haven't used mysqli in a little while, but shouldn't the strings in your query be wrapped using ' or \" ? "UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherSalt = '$salt' ... "

Comment: That's correct, Jeffery. Even better would be to use `SET TeacherSalt = ?` and then include `$salt` in the `bind_param` call. The main reason to use prepared statements is to avoid doing variable interpolation.

Comment: Just to keep these multiple response threads in synch: the OP wasn't even able to echo "$query".  It's important to make sure that the PHP query matches the expected query.  Moreover, I'm now wondering if PHP might be skipping the entire "update" block.  See the above thread for more details...

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the sql query string. Variables like $salt and $newpassword should be in single quotes so that string would contain TeacherSalt='random' and not TeacherSalt=random.

So you should replace

```
$query = "UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherSalt = $salt, TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT($newpassword,$salt)) WHERE TeacherUserName = ?";
```

with

```
$query = "UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherSalt = '$salt', TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT('$newpassword','$salt')) WHERE TeacherUserName = 'yoursearchparam'";
```

Hope that works.

Comment: +1: I think you hit it on the head.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't see any error checking or handling.

2) I'm confused about variables "$username", "$newpassword", "$dbTeacherUsername", "$dbTeacherPassword", etc.  Are you sure you're using the right name(s) in the right place(s)?

3) At a minimum, please check for "$stmt->execute() == false", and display PDO "errorInfo" as appropriate.

Please post back what you find.

Comment: Ok I have done some error reporting and I am getting a fatal error and warning stating this: `Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: (42S22/1054): Unknown column 'i6xX2u35GvDo1vegznNkS34uO903y.XaHlp1hFXd' in 'field list' in ... on line 36`
....
`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in on line 38`

Comment: Cool - progress :)  Please echo out the variables "$query" and "$username" before you call "execute()".  Also try cutting/pasting the same values into the mysql command line and see what happens.  Please post back what you find.  I'll bet you're probably getting illegal metacharacters...

Comment: I tried to echo $query and username but nothing is appearing. Anyway in the sql command if I include this `"UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherSalt = 'sample', TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT('fl3od4RrLcfmnnzedkbLqucR2QUfk5J6pPQhe5Eg','sample')) WHERE TeacherUserName = 'j.lu'";` The successfully changes the old password to the new password and the word 'sample' is inserted into the "TeacherSalt" column. Just need to somehow get it working in php

Comment: Q: Any idea why "query and username aren't appearing"???  Perhaps "if (isset($_POST['submit']))" evaluates to "false"; perhaps something else.  But I would focus on getting them to echo: whatever fixes "echo" *might* resolve the entire problem!